# Platform compatibility issue

Tags: android, sdk

Android platform sample codes and reference from the Android developer site is based on platform 1.5 I understand that newer platforms can support applications developed on older platforms but the reciprocal is not applicable which makes sense but is the coding different? Are codes that were used for developing 1.5 apps still useful in newer platforms or have newer classes and methods replaced them? It seems that eclipse is producing a lot of coding errors in its samples in relation to classes and methods also if a app that was developd by a IME is unable to be viewed on the emulator or how can it be tested or retrieved on the device? Any advice is welcome...sorry it's so long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the SDK folders, on windows it will be `c:\<SDK location>\samples\android-x` the samples are located according to api level so they will definitely be compatible there so I would look at these.

To answer your other questions, yes there are api changes as you go up an api level so they should cause warnings or compilation errors and some classes may even be completely removed. Generally the lower level stuff shouldn't change too much but the most important thing is that the semantics change rarely unless there was a design flaw in the original implementations.

The release notes for each version usually points out what has changed and the online documentation is generally superb in my opinion in informing you what exactly is deprecated. If you are just targeting old devices then your emulator is just set to target those api levels but if you are concerned about functionality then you could code using api 1.5 say, and run an ICS api level 15 emulator and check everything works OK, if not then you decide what the best strategy should be. Generally I would advise to target Android 2.2 and above for mobile devices and 3.0 for tablets but really it is up to you.

Comment: I did and it's giving class errors such as this class is not instantiated and even some of the strings are not showing the appropriate words instead it gives @string/.... When I check the strings XML everything is fine...these errors confuse I assumed the samples would be correct to learn and build from...

Comment: Sounds odd, I would delete the project from Eclipse (but not of course delete the source code), restart Eclipse, load the project again, do a full rebuild and see it is now fine

Comment: I did and you are correct everything looks good now also in your professional opinion I know samples are as they are but would u say technically they are correct and that developer tweaks are of preference rather then necessity? Im wondering would the samples function on their on with mere graphical modifications

Comment: @VictoriaC If the api samples do what you want then fine you only need to tweak them but it depends on the complexity of your app, once you go above 3-4 activities and start to want lots of different kinds of widgets and interactivity then you find the sample code is insufficient and you have to write most of it yourself but the sample code show you the easiest way to demonstrate a concept or api usage. After that I recommned open source android code, the android cookbook and here of course. You can accept my answer now as a thank you :)

Comment: I will and thank you!! You gave me what I needed to know and more!! My brain can relax now!! lol

Answer (score 0):

three are classes that are deprecated and can't be used anymore, like Contacts.People. There are also classes that are deprecated, they can still be used but they should be avoided in new projects. And there are new classes that were not available before. In some cases like for Fragment there are compatibility support libs to use the new features on the old platform but this is not true for classes like for example PreferenceFragment that are not supported on old platforms.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense I guess that's where the error codes are coming from....I'm building in 2.1 but th samples were from 1.5 and do not reflect updated or outdated classes/methods....that's just my assumption...